# how to reorganize the content of the layout depends on the number of views inside it

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-gridlayout

I have ten imageviews inside gridlayout, and I make columncount 5 so after five image views it will go to next line, now if I want to make some image view visibility gone, it should be reorganize depends in the number of imageviews, but the problem it shows the spaces of the gone views!!

this is my xml code

```
    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:columnCount="5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:tint="@color/brown"
            android:id="@+id/ivImage1"
            android:background="@color/brown"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/ivImage2"
            android:background="@color/brown"
            android:tint="@color/brown"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/ivImage3"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:background="@color/brown"
            android:tint="@color/brown"/>


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/ivImage4"
            android:background="@color/brown"
            android:tint="@color/brown"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/ivImage5"
            android:background="@color/brown"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:tint="@color/brown"/>



        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/ivImage6"
            android:background="@color/brown"
            android:tint="@color/brown"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/ivImage7"
            android:background="@color/brown"
            android:tint="@color/brown"/>



        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/ivImage8"
            android:background="@color/brown"
            android:tint="@color/brown"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/ivImage9"
            android:background="@color/brown"
            android:tint="@color/brown"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/ivImage10"
            android:background="@color/brown"
            android:tint="@color/brown"/>


    </GridLayout>
```

what I want is if some of views gone the other views should take the place of it, hope my question is clear
thanks in advance

Comment: Are you adding content to your grid programmatically? I mean, is there an array you iterate over in order to populate the grid?

Comment: @rob no I didnt, actually I want to make all of the Image views gone and in the codes I will make some of them visible depends in some codition, but for now I just try to see how it will look in xml if I did make some of them gone but its not look as I thought, if there is another way to do it programmatically  I dont know?

Comment: better you use gridView it will be managed itself and set count as you need so coud be handled easy

Comment: @GIBINTHOMAS ok, how I do that am not familiar with the gridview, you mean the imageviews will be created programmatically inside the gridview?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a grid view like this and set image in a arraylist

```
 <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gv_photosGrid"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:horizontalSpacing="3dp"
                android:numColumns="5"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:verticalSpacing="3dp" />
```

Initailise the gridView as

```
    gv_photosGrid = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gv_photosGrid);
    gv_photosGrid.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Create a adapter as

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater laytout_inflator;
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();


    public Adapter(Context _context, ArrayList<String> list) {
        context = _context;
        this.list = list;
        laytout_inflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int possition, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        ViewHolder view_holder = new ViewHolder();
        if (arg1 == null) {
            arg1 = laytout_inflator.inflate(R.layout.template, null);
            view_holder = intitViews(arg1);
            arg1.setTag(view_holder);
        } else {
            view_holder = (ViewHolder) arg1.getTag();
        }
//        view_holder.iv_photo.setImage

        return arg1;
    }

    public ViewHolder intitViews(View view) {
        ViewHolder view_holder = new ViewHolder();
        view_holder.iv_photo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_userLogo);]
        return view_holder;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView iv_photo;
    }
}
```

Comment: For your need set all colors in an array list and pass to the list as the list object as i have mentioned

Comment: I didnt get you litteI bit, I used your code, and its work fine but images repeated as the number of the arraylist size, and the array list in your code with type string? I have to change it?! how I set the images ?

Comment: I solve it, Now I know thank you for your help, I put the arraylist with type integers and set the image in the getView method

Comment: Thanks for the feedback ,I didn't know what type you have created the images sorry

Answer (score 2):

Use GridView instead of GridLayout and Use: ImageView.setVisibilty(View.GONE);

Comment: how I can add Imageview inside gridview in the xml its I think not possible?

Comment: no it is not possible use adapter in java to add imageview